# Is every vector subspace also affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

*I have a slight doubt because of some stuff I read.*

**Is every vector subspace also an affine subspace?**

If not, can you state a counter-example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can consider a vector space to be an affine space whose underlying translation space is itself.

A casual way of describing affine spaces is as "vector spaces where you forget where the origin is".

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course any subspace may be considered as an affine space over itself.

Refer also to [Vector spaces as affine spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Vector_spaces_as_affine_spaces).